# Laravel:eloquent-sluggable

Tags: php, laravel

Hello when i want to install cviebrock eloquent-sluggable package i run the following error please guide me 
thank you

This is my terminal text when it gives me this error:

```
H:\website\xampp\htdocs\laravel2>composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
Using version ^7.0 for cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable ^7.0 -> satisfiable by cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable[7.0.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 7.0.0 requires illuminate/config ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev], illuminate/config[7.x-dev, v7.0.0
, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v6.18.3].
    - don't install illuminate/config 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/config v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.18.3, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.18.3].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone encountered same problem. You must use **match** the Laravel version to eloquent-sluggable package version. Visit here [eloquent sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable)

and if still has an error. try this

`composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 6.0.*`

use `6.0.*` instead of `^6.0`

Answer (score 1):

This is a dependency version problem. You're trying to install `cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable ^7.0` which is requires `laravel/framework ^7.0` but you have `laravel/framework 6.18.3`. More info [here](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable#installation).

Try installing a lower version of `cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable`(preferably `^6.0`) by doing `composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable ^6.0`.

Comment: I guess there is a dependency problem. Ive encountered the same scenario. I had 6.2 laravel version then  `composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable ^6.0`. Unfortunately no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having this issue in the future while upgrading from laravel 6 to 7.
Update your "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable" to version 7 like so  "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^7.0" in your composer.json file

Answer (score 0):

Laravel have a default class for slug `Str::slug($variable_or_plain_text, ‘the symbol you want to replaced by space’);`

Answer (score 0):

for this package

```
'slug' => [
                'source' => ['title']
            ]
```

how can we implement an auto-update slug when updating the title field

Comment: Are you asking a question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try for Laravel 8

composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 8.0.*